# how to open query editor in mysql administrator

Tags: mysql, mysqladministrator

i have installed **MySQL administrator**. But i can't see the query window.

please tell me what should i do to set up **query window** and execute that query ?

Answer (score 3):

```
   You Can use following GUI Tool
1. Workbench
2. Sequel Pro
3. HeidiSQL
4.phpMyAdmin
5. dbForge Studio
```

Comment: ya i know these tools but i have read somewhere that you can execute the query in the MySQL Administrator and i didn't found. So i asked question ?